# How do I make a CURL call using my app script codes

Tags: google-apps-script, curl

The example code was given to me as this.

Sample Call

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://authentication.carfax.ca/oauth/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: did=s%3Av0%3Ad4c8e610-067c-11ec-84ad-
83a048983dd7.IfTEs0EGLJ7r5kYxspPDGaSaw9fs2WPxYv5K%2FJv6Rpg; 
did_compat=s%3Av0%3Ad4c8e610-067c-11ec-84ad-
83a048983dd7.IfTEs0EGLJ7r5kYxspPDGaSaw9fs2WPxYv5K%2FJv6Rpg' \
--data-urlencode 'audience=https://api.carfax.ca' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=PROVIDEDBYINTEGRATIONSUPPORT' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=PROVIDEDBYINTEGRATIONSUPPORT'
```

My App script code is written as the following where client_id is changed to my actuall client id and client_secret is also updated. I can't get this code to work. Can anyone suggest how i should rewrite the code?

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = 'https://authentication.carfax.ca/oauth/token';
  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie': 'did=s%3Av0%3Ad4c8e610-067c-11ec-84ad-83a048983dd7.IfTEs0EGLJ7r5kYxspPDGaSaw9fs2WPxYv5K%2FJv6Rpg;did_compat=s%3Av0%3Ad4c8e610-067c-11ec-84ad-83a048983dd7.IfTEs0EGLJ7r5kYxspPDGaSaw9fs2WPxYv5K%2FJv6Rpg',
    "data-urlencode": {
      'audience': 'https://api.carfax.ca',
      'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
      'client_id': 'xT18269vTVFk6Cy2QUjSyzVxs8BZcN6j',
      'client_secret': '1Fz57F-lUuTZODoICC68ZUqSQoL6MCx4xR8PP9Bqfh6qGJThCC59uRZkJQF75HOK'
    }
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
  var text = response.getResponseCode();
  Logger.log(headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script.

  ```
    curl --location --request POST 'https://authentication.carfax.ca/oauth/token' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --header 'Cookie: did=s%3Av0%3Ad4c8e610-067c-11ec-84ad-
    83a048983dd7.IfTEs0EGLJ7r5kYxspPDGaSaw9fs2WPxYv5K%2FJv6Rpg; 
    did_compat=s%3Av0%3Ad4c8e610-067c-11ec-84ad-
    83a048983dd7.IfTEs0EGLJ7r5kYxspPDGaSaw9fs2WPxYv5K%2FJv6Rpg' \
    --data-urlencode 'audience=https://api.carfax.ca' \
    --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
    --data-urlencode 'client_id=PROVIDEDBYINTEGRATIONSUPPORT' \
    --data-urlencode 'client_secret=PROVIDEDBYINTEGRATIONSUPPORT'
  ```

In this case, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie': 'did=s%3Av0%3Ad4c8e610-067c-11ec-84ad-83a048983dd7.IfTEs0EGLJ7r5kYxspPDGaSaw9fs2WPxYv5K%2FJv6Rpg;did_compat=s%3Av0%3Ad4c8e610-067c-11ec-84ad-83a048983dd7.IfTEs0EGLJ7r5kYxspPDGaSaw9fs2WPxYv5K%2FJv6Rpg',
    "data-urlencode": {
      'audience': 'https://api.carfax.ca',
      'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
      'client_id': 'xT18269vTVFk6Cy2QUjSyzVxs8BZcN6j',
      'client_secret': '1Fz57F-lUuTZODoICC68ZUqSQoL6MCx4xR8PP9Bqfh6qGJThCC59uRZkJQF75HOK'
    }
  };

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
```

#### To:

```
var options = {
  "headers": { 'Cookie': 'did=s%3Av0%3Ad4c8e610-067c-11ec-84ad-83a048983dd7.IfTEs0EGLJ7r5kYxspPDGaSaw9fs2WPxYv5K%2FJv6Rpg;did_compat=s%3Av0%3Ad4c8e610-067c-11ec-84ad-83a048983dd7.IfTEs0EGLJ7r5kYxspPDGaSaw9fs2WPxYv5K%2FJv6Rpg' },
  "payload": {
    'audience': 'https://api.carfax.ca',
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': 'xT18269vTVFk6Cy2QUjSyzVxs8BZcN6j',
    'client_secret': '1Fz57F-lUuTZODoICC68ZUqSQoL6MCx4xR8PP9Bqfh6qGJThCC59uRZkJQF75HOK'
  }
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

#### Note:

- In your curl command, `Cookie` is used. In this case, the cookie might be required to be updated. If an error occurs, please check this.
- If an error like the status code `403` occurs, I'm worried that in this case, Google side might not be able to access to this URL.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)